# Why is the set $U_i \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ defined by $x_i\neq 0$ a variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

In chapter 1 section 3 of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, the following proposition is given:

Let $U_i \subset \mathbb P^n$ be the open set defined by the equation $x_i \neq 0$. Then the mapping $\phi_i:U_i\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^n$ is an isomorphism of varieties, where
$$
\phi(a_0,\ldots,a_n) = (a_0/a_i,\ldots,a_n/a_i)
$$
with the term $a_i/a_i$ omitted.

I am confused because to suggest $U_i$ is a variety is to suggest that $\mathbb{P}^n$ is not connected, as this would make $U_i$ clopen. Am I misunderstanding the proposition, or is something else going on here that I am missing?

Comment: This is saying that $U_i$ is open with respect to the topology on $\mathbb{P}^n$. Note that this does not mean $U_i$ is closed. $U_i$ is closed on the subspace topology $U_i\cap \mathbb{P}^n$ as it's the whole space but $U_i$ itself is not closed in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: Looking at daruma's comment from the other side, the proposition says that we can regard $\mathbf{A^n}$ as an open of $\mathbf{P^n}$ (by setting one coordinate $=1$). By varying which coordinate we set equal to one, we can cover $\mathbf{P^n}$ by open affines $\mathbf{A^n}=U_i$.

Answer (score 1):

After reflection I realized that I forgot that an isomorphism of varieties extends to quasi-varieties - i.e. open subsets of varieties. So the statement I took issue with doesn't necessitate that $U_i$ be closed in it's ambient projective space.